# Retain IEnumerable<T> value during postback

Tags: asp.net

I have an IEnumerable< T> which is declared on the page like this:

IEnumerable< Person> person;

When the page postsback, the person list is null. How can I retain the values of person list without declaring it as static? Sr. devs in my company say that you should not declare the list as static.

Comment: the type of the variable should have no bearing on whether it is persisted across postbacks...

Comment: did the Sr. Devs also tell you how to solve the problem?

Comment: yes they told me to store the person list in viewstate object when it's created. Is that the best way

Comment: so, is there a reason why you don't listen to your senior devs?

Comment: Just confirming things with other Sr dev's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sr. Devs are right. No static (rather read C# basics - really bad idea).

Variables in general do not preserve between postbacks. Read up on using the SESSION or the VIEWSTATE for storing information for a user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know more about page life-cycle. When page is rendered to the client its object is thrown away. If you have any field in your page you need to initialize it explicitely every time before you are going to use it.